# I try to update data in my sqlite3 address book python program, but the function cannot update my data

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax

I try to update data in my sqlite3 address book python program, therefore I type this function. However, the function cannot update my data. There's no syntax error, but the code just doesn't work. It said 'near 'set' there is a syntax error. Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you.

```
def update_contact():
    name = input('update which name?')
    a = input('phone')
    b = input('address')
    results = cur.execute("UPDATE contact_book set phone = ? set address = ? WHERE name = ?", 
                (a, b, name,))
#cur = con.cursor(), con = sq.connect('contact_book.db')
    view_contact()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit the changes to the database whenever you change the contents, for it to be saved

```
results = cur.execute("UPDATE contact_book set phone = ? set address = ? WHERE name = ?", (a, b, name,))

con.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you, I've add it but now it returns a syntax error and I don't know what's the problem with my code.

Comment: @Becky1122 Try to remove the ```,``` like this: ```(a, b, name)```

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one `SET` keyword in an `UPDATE` query:

`UPDATE contact_book set phone = ?, address = ? WHERE name = ?`